# Android: Compositing multiple layers of video into a new video

Tags: android, video, buffer, layer, compositing

I have some basic experience with video and imagery in Android using SurfaceViews, mediarecorder, VideoView etc. What I would like to do however is to composite multiple layers of video (generally with a top layer having an alpha channel to expose the layer behind it) in a buffer and save the result to a new video file. What would also be useful is to be able to perform compositing functions like "screen", "multiply", or "overlay".

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: @user1808585: Dont add tag name in the title of the question.